# Why all the elements changed to the new item when I add a new item to an existing list?

Tags: python, list, loops

I am writing a loop to add new element to an existing list. But I found when I add a new element to the list, the length of the list increases by one, but all the elements in the list are replaced by the new element. I am looking forward to your hand!

I have tried to write a simple code to add element to an existing list in a loop in console, but the result is right. So I really wonder what my fault is in the former program.

```py
#construct the boundary of the set and the given point
beginPoint = middlePoint(projectionInSet(givenPoint), givenPoint)
pointSetBoundary = [beginPoint,]
print(pointSetBoundary)
#rightside of the beginning point
rightPoint = beginPoint
print("Begin Point: ", rightPoint)
projection = projectionInSet(rightPoint)
print("Begin Projection: ", projection )
[k, b] = perpendicualrBisector(projectionInSet(givenPoint), givenPoint)
stepRight = 0.01 
while rightPoint[0] <= 10 and rightPoint[1] <= 10 and rightPoint[0] >= 0 and rightPoint[1] >= 0: 
    rightPoint[0] = rightPoint[0] + stepRight
    rightPoint[1] = k * rightPoint[0] + b
    if distance(projectionInSet(rightPoint), projection) > 0.000001:
        projection = projectionInSet(rightPoint)
        [k, b] = perpendicualrBisector(projection, givenPoint)
        if k >= 0:
            stepRight = 0.01
        else:
            stepRight = -0.01
    pointSetBoundary.append(rightPoint)
    print(pointSetBoundary)
print("Right Boundaries completed!")
```

I expect when the new rightPoint adds to the former list without changing the existing elements.

Answer (score 0):

After posting the question, I suddenly realized that the element which I adds to the list changes the whole time. That's very sorry. To save your time, I close this question.

At the beginning of the while loop, I changed the value of rightPoint points to. However, the former element of the list shared the same memory space. So their contents changes at the same time.